# Change site collection administrator of the content db in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have site collection and added site collection administrator after I have restored the content database from the staging server after that its collection administrator name is added and deleted other administrator

so I can't open the site it shows the site not shared with you.

> Sorry this site hasn't been shared with you

I have tried changing the secondary site collection administrator to but no use. kindly help me to resolve this

Comment: try to set using powershell. that should work.

Comment: I have tried that too but still it show "sorry the site not is not shared with you" error

Comment: Execute powershell with farm account. Also from farm account you should be able to navigate to central admin and update site administrator.

Comment: Yes i have runned the command under farm control and i have add another user by power shell command but nothing works

Comment: what is the authentication method being used in Production and test farm? are both farm on the same domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to edit your SharePoitoint administrator via Central Administration as the following:

- Open Central Administration > Application Management > Change Site Collection Administrators.
  [image]
- Select your Web Application > Select the site collection.
- Remove the old site collection administrators then add the new site collection administrators of the current farm.

[image]

Comment: Yes i have did this one but am getting the same error

Comment: Which error? !!

Comment: Sorry this sit is not shared with you

Comment: I have enabled anonymous to but still am getting aite not shared with you

Comment: it's annoyed issue with multiple reasons,  could you provide us the step by step that you have did to migrate from Staging to Production

Comment: I have created a team site and restored the content database backup file thats all i did and while accesing the site it shows access denied so i went to central admin and changed the site collection adminstrator and tried but not worked so i used powershell command to add secondary use that too not worked so i have enabled anonyums acces that to not worked

Comment: My colleague added a script in master page that the site will expired on or before some date now i removed that script in master page its working.. thanks for your support:)